# Antonym of petitioner or "target of a request"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a way to describe the target of a request/petition. This could be a person, an institution or a machine (common in the tech world). The word *"receiver"* is not specific enough for my taste and I feel it not only implies some kind of transfer but also a specific direction. I am trying to avoid this connotation because the target of a request could be requested to provide something, thus making it the opposite of a receiver.

I tried to google several variants of *"word for target of a petition/request"*, but couldn't find anything useful. Then I decided to look for antonyms and thought *"petitioner"* would be a good search term.
I looked at [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/petitioner), but it doesn't show any antonyms for my request. Neither does [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/petitioner). I did find 13 antonyms at [Power Thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/petitioner/antonyms), but the only one that seems to have some semantic match is *"responsor"*, which Merriam-Webster in turn defines as

> the receiver component of an interrogator

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/371566/what-word-is-closest-to-inquisitee-the-target-of-an-inquisition) goes in a similar direction, but has not been answered.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33240/antonym-of-to-request) also goes in a similar direction, but then takes a computer-specific turn.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/249791/target-or-subject-of-a-requirement-or-criteria) has almost the same basic idea, but has also not (really) been answered.

**Is there even such a word in the English language?**

Comment: how does one make a petition to a machine (apparently common)?

Comment: @depperm: One doesn't, but the OP wrote "request/petition", so see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request–response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request–response).

Comment: @ruakh I am familiar with web requests, I never really associated it with petitioning. For computers/technology the target would be a server

Comment: @deperm Not necessarily always a server. But even if it were always a server that would be a word for the concrete thing, where I am rather looking for the term for the abstract concept.

Comment: The target of a petition is not the "antonym"  of petitioner. Like a wide receiver in football is not the antonym of quarterback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Petitionee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/petitionee)**

> a person cited to answer or defend against a petition

**[Server](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/server)**

> the main computer in a network which provides files and services that are used by the other computers

**[Requestee](https://glosbe.com/en/en/requestee)** (not from MW)

> A person from whom something is requested

Comment: Yeah, or maybe responder.